# Convertir consulta SQL a Eloquent Laravel 5.6

Tags: sql, laravel-5, eloquent

Tengo la siguiente consulta SQL para obtener agrupado y ordenado por meses la suma de precios de tres productos, lo cual hace sin problema

```
 SELECT name, SUM(precio) AS total, mes 
 FROM productos
 GROUP BY mes 
 ORDER BY mes DESC;
```

El resultado que obtengo es el siguiente:

```
+------+-------+---------+
| name | total | mes     |
+------+-------+---------+
| alfa | 138   | marzo   |
| beta | 249   | febrero |
| gama | 372   | enero   |
+------+-------+---------+
```

Intento hacer la consulta en Eloquent, de este modo

```
$data = Producto::
        select(DB::raw("name, mes, SUM(precio) as count"))
        ->groupBy("mes")
        ->orderBy('mes', 'DESC')
        ->get();
    return $data;
```

Pero solo me funciona si en `config/databases.php`

> Pongo el modo strict en false, lo cual no quiero hacer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dentro del Group by, agregue la segunda columna name para que me lograra ejecutar la consulta y este es el resultado final

```
$data = Producto::
        select(DB::raw("name, mes, SUM(precio) as count"))
        ->groupBy("name", "mes")
        ->orderBy('name', 'DESC')
        ->get();
        return $data;
```